# Jmeter token-based authorization mechanism

Tags: jmeter

I've developed a JAXRS based REST WebAPI. It's under a token-based authorization mechanism. It's very similar to OAuth 2.0:

So, I need to create a [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) Test in order to test my webapi.

> ```
>     1. Get Authorization Code (on http://www.host.com/authz)
>      Request:
>       [ Header: 'response_type', Value: 'code']
>       [ Header: 'client_id', Value: 'FIXED ID STRING']
>       [ Header: 'username', Value: '$USER provided from a data source' ]
>       [ Header: 'password', Value: '$PASSWORD provided from a data source'] 
>      Response:
>       [ Header: 'code', Value: '%AuthorizationCode' ]
>       [ Header: 'expires_in', Value: '100'(seconds)]
> ```
>
> ```
>     2. Get Access Token
>      Request:
>       [Header: 'grant_type', Value: 'authorization_code']
>       [Header: 'code', Value: '%AuthorizationCode provided on the last request']
>       [Header: 'client_id', Value: 'FIXED ID STRING']
>      Response:
>       [Header: 'access_token', Value: '%AccessToken']
>       [Header: 'expires_in', Value: '500'(seconds)]
>       [Header: 'refresh_token', value: '%RefrestToken']
> ```

After that dance, I've gotten an **%AuthorizationCode**, **%AccessToken** and a **%RefreshToken**.

From now on, I'm able to access to webapi using these codes.

> ```
>     ForEach user in a datasource:
>      Loop Forever:
>       Send Http request each X seconds (on http://www.host.com/webapi)
>        [Header: 'Authorization', Value: 'OAuth + %AccessToken']
> ```

I've absolutly no idea how to build this.

For example: I would like to test with 50 users and perform a webapi method 100 times along 6 min.

- How to provide several user information to JMeter?
- How to build this OAuth-like dance?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Providing different credentials is fairly easy, the most commonly used Test Element is [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) where you can keep username/password combinations
2. You can add username and password (as well as `code`, etc.) to request headers via HTTP Header Manager. Add it as a child of the HTTP Request and populate with desired header names and values. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) defined in the CSV Data Set config will also play
3. You can extract `AccessToken` from the response headers using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
4. Provide `Authorization` header via HTTP Header Manager like in point 2.